# Typescript throws error on build but no errors while executing in cmd

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I have updated my typescript to 3.4.1 and after that while executing ng serve it shows no errors but when i open the application in vs 2017 it throws many errors related to ts.

Comment: vscode. webstorm is better.

Comment: @yantrab what a comment...

Comment: you can have other ts version in vscode and what you are building with.